# Is every formally real field isomorphic to a subfield of the reals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, real-numbers, quadratic-forms

A formally real field is a field $K$ such that $-1$ is not a sum of squares in $K$. Clearly subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ are formally real. I also know finite fields and algebraically closed fields are never formally real. Then the next example I can think of is a field of rational functions of a formally real field, for example $\mathbb{Q}(t)$. But then mapping $t$ to some transcendental number in $\mathbb{R}$, e.g. $\pi$, I get an isomorphism to a subfield of the reals, in this case $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Is there any example where I cannot get an isomorphism into a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$? Is this possible in division rings/ skew-fields?

Comment: What about a formally real field of cardinality $>2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: Wouldnt $Q(\zeta_3)$ be formally real ?

Comment: @Testcase $(\zeta_3)^2+(\zeta_3^2)^2=\zeta_3^2+\zeta_3=-1$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't know of any such fields. What are examples of them?

Comment: For example, an ultraproduct of an uncountable number of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ should give a formally real field which has arbitrarily large cardinality.

Comment: Or $\mathbb{Q}((t_a)_{a\subset \mathbb{R}})$ should be a “too large” formally real field.

Comment: Otherwise $K=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{R}((t^{1/n}))$ its algebraic closure is $K[i] \cong \Bbb{C}$ (need the axiom of choice to prove $\cong$) but it is neither isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$ nor to a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$. The order on $K$ is to compare the first non-zero Laurent series coefficient. $\Bbb{R}(t)$ and $\Bbb{R}((t))$ are ordered as well and again they are not isomorphic to a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: A related fact is that "every ordered archimedean field is order isomorphic to a subfield of $\mathbb {R} $". Note that ordered fields are formally real and hence adding the extra archimedean property makes it isomorphic to a subfield of reals.